# Cannot use namespace 'ResponseLike' as a type

Tags: npm, caching, aws-cdk

I got this error when I AWS cdk deploy command.I got this error Cannot use namespace 'ResponseLike' as a type.

My package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "fabber_aws_v1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "fabber_aws_v1": "bin/fabber_aws_v1.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.131.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.131.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.41.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2": "^1.170.1",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha": "^2.41.0-alpha.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers": "^1.170.1",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers-alpha": "^2.41.0-alpha.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations": "^1.170.1",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations-alpha": "^2.41.0-alpha.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.170.1",
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.131.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.131.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.41.0",
    "constructs": "^10.1.52",
    "crypto-randomuuid": "^1.0.0",
    "latest-version": "^7.0.0",
    "npm": "^8.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
}
```

I got some solution in GitHub but that was not working for me. Github Link [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/62099)

Answer (score 1):

Orienting on your [URL](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/62099), nothing worked for me as well, but the [last](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/62099#discussioncomment-3663031) solution with slight modification:

In `package.json`, instead of

```
"overrides": {
  "@types/cacheable-request": "8.3.1"
}
```

i did

```
"overrides": {
  "got": "12.4.1"
}
```

This might lead to a complition error, but can be resolved by setting `"skipLibCheck": true` in `tsconfig.json`.